# Magento 2 : Load admin grid with pre-defined filter

Tags: magento2, php

I looked for hours but I'm not able to pre-filter a default admin grid like the admin product grid.
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you define grid collection thought layout than you can use updater to add default filter.

```
<argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">
    Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Resource\News\Collection
    <updater>Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Resource\News\Collection\Updater</updater>
</argument>
```

and

```
<?php
namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Resource\News\Collection;

    class CollectionUpdater implements \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Argument\UpdaterInterface
    {

    /**
     * Update grid collection according to chosen order
     *
     * @param \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Resource\News\Collection $argument
     * @return \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Resource\News\Collection
     */
    public function update($argument)
    {
        $argument->addFieldToFilter('you_field', 'value');

        return $argument;
    }
}
```

or Extend Grid block

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            foreach ($this->getDefaultFilter() as $field => $value) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
            }
        }
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }   
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply !

I tried to apply it to the admin product grid but I'm not able to find where the collection is set. But I would like to preset the store filter and not necessarily custom the collection.

Thanks !